# golang: Using a defined interface in a Map Value

Tags: dictionary, go, types, interface

in the linked playground example, I define a type:

```
type DoMap map[int]func(Doer) string
```

Where `Doer` in an interface type that I define.

I implement the interface on a concrete type `MyDoer`.  I'd like to be able to construct a `DoMap` where entries into that map contain functions like both of the following:

```
func(Doer) string // this works
func(*MyDoer) string // this doesn't
func(MyDoer) string // more-or-less the same idea, also doesn't
```

I can't, and although it's obvious they are different types, I wonder why I can't since function ensures I have to provide a `MyDoer` which implements `Doer`.

Isn't that enough to ensure I will fulfill my contract with the function?

Is there another way of achieving this?

https://play.golang.org/p/sJ2Rg3neL7

#### Update

Some comments are of the form "they are different" "that's the spec" but I can pass a `MyDoer` to a function that accepts a `Doer` - if the interface is implemented: why does putting it into a map change the result?

#### Update 2

There's a request to explain the "real problem" and a question of why I can't just use a map of types.  I'll try best I can:

`DoMap` cannot be a map of types.  I am writing a library that allows developers to succinctly define state machines, which succeed or fail to transition, based on the output of a developer written function (business logic) that accepts a developer defined type (business message). the library exists to ensure that the series of transitions can be serialized and recorded elsewhere and subsequently verified by third party users of the library.  I didn't say all that originally, because it misses the point - there isn't a simple answer.

Now I feel like I am annoying everyone with my impertinent questions, and since I don't exactly have Rob Pike on speed dial, I'll probably delete this, unless some one is willing to trust that I need to do what I need to do, and suggest something.

Comment: No, it’s not enough, the signature is not the same. Why do you want to do that? (This may help others to suggest alternatives).

Comment: " I wonder why I can't since function ensures I have to provide a MyDoer which implements Doer." this doesn't make the type the same. Different types are different types. Go has no supertypes with subtypes being also of supertype. That's how the type system works.

Comment: Go is not really object oriented, though you can mimic it in many ways. This is not one of them.

Comment: as the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Properties_of_types_and_values) state: `Two types are either identical or different. `

Comment: Sure - they are different types, but I can pass a `MyDoer` to a function that accepts a `Doer` - that's the whole point of interfaces.  Why does putting it in a map make the result somehow different?

Comment: Because you aren't passing a `Doer` you are passing a `func(Doer) string` the compiler doesn't care that `MyDoer` implements `Doer`, the function type must match exactly.

Comment: it clearly doesn't, but should it? could it? Is there a simple reason I've missed that it can't? Most likely this isn't something that comes up often, and I've clearly created an artificial example, but it did come up in my project.

Comment: You've updated your question to basically say you understand but don't like the answer. *That's just how Go works.* You defined a specific value type in the `map`, and you must use that type, period. Any discussion beyond that is out of scope for SO, possibly better suited to one of the Go mailing lists.

Comment: they are taking proposals now for go2: https://github.com/golang/proposal

Comment: I'm not nearly smart enough to make a language design proposal.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't outlined a concrete problem (the why). This makes it hard to suggest alternatives, because it looks like you're trying to recreate another language in go.

In order of preference, you can use the type system as intended:

```
type DoMap map[int]func(Doer) string

type Doer interface {
    Do() int
    AlsoDo() int
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uPzoOZiLQG

Or you can bypass the type system of course:

```
type DoMap map[int]interface{}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lfKPkwhOGa

But I wouldn't recommend that - better to work with the tools the language gives you, rather than trying to bend them out of shape.

The intent of the interface is to advertise a contract about the functions - they require this of their argument, and no more. But then you also want to call AlsoDo on the argument, so if you want to do that, put it in the contract. Then all will work as you intend. The contract for the function should be published next to the function as in your example, it should be under your control.

[EDIT]
Finally, if you don't control the types passed in, perhaps you should rethink the idea of your map. It could be a map[int]Doer where Doer is an interface (which you should control). This lets you advertise what you require in your library, and users put whatever type they want in there (with whatever other dependencies they want).

```
// Library 
type DoMap map[int]Doer

type Doer interface {
    Do() int
}

// Client 
type MyDoer struct {
    myint int
}

func (d *MyDoer) Do() int {
    fmt.Println(d.AlsoDo())
    return d.myint + 1
}

func (d *MyDoer) AlsoDo() int {
    return d.myint + 2
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cs01C8bSKo

[EDIT2] Final edit, if building an fsm management chain, you might find this little project inspirational. It should definitely be doable without much trouble, just not exactly as in your first attempt of a map of function which can take any type:

https://github.com/ryanfaerman/fsm

Comment: The problem is that this map bridges the gap between library and user code, so the user might want `AlsoDo` but the library can't know that.

Comment: This second example suggests some possibility, but in my case it just moves the problem around - I need to make a library that doesn't know developer defined concrete types, and define a map-type that uses them, without requiring the user to write type assertions.

Comment: Maybe you should try explaining the real problem, explaining all the constraints by editing your answer above. This is a little abstract and you're focussed on the limits of the type system, rather than what you actually need to do. Are you sure for example that you need a map of funcs that act on types, not a map of types?

Comment: sorry if my update sounded snarky, i realize you are genuinely trying to help, and thanks for that.  the list of constraints does not easily fit the SO Q&A format

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the map[int]Doer is not workable?